# Прадеды и пращуры

Tags: этимология, значение-слов

Прадед — это понятно: "пра-дед". Есть даже не очень часто употребляемое "праотцы".
А вот кто такие в этом случае пращуры?
Та же приставка "пра-", но что такое "щур"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ИЗ СЛОВАРЯ ШАНСКОГО

Пращур – общеславянское слово, от утраченного шуръ, предположительно того же корня, что «шурин».  Шурин – суффиксальное производное от шуръ (ст.-сл. вариант), возможно от «шить» со значением «соединенный, связанный».

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ К ОТВЕТУ

РЕЛИГИЯ СЛАВЯН

Славянская мифология и религия формировались на протяжении долгого периода в процессе выделения древних славян из индоевропейской общности.  Восточные славяне накануне принятия христианства верили в единого Бога-Творца, материальным воплощением которого являлся огонь. Огонь (индоир. – Агни) является одним из наиболее почитаемых божеств всех индоевропейских народов. В праславянской древности этим Богом-Творцом был Сварог – небесный огонь (но не Перун - бог-громовержец, покровитель князя и дружины).  Самые ранние сведения о божествах древнерусского язычества могут дать материалы договоров Руси с византийцами, заключённых после походов в 945и 971 годах: «И если кто с русской стороны помыслит разрушить такую любовь… да не получат помощи ни от Бога, ни от Перуна».

ЧУР, СЛАВЯНСКИЙ БОГ ОХРАНЫ

Чур - низшее божество в восточнославянской мифологии. В его обязанности входит охрана межей, границ земельных, да и вообще границ. Чур охраняет родовые и племенные владения, и нечистые силы не могут переступить их границы. На межах, границах своих владений ставят истукана с вырезанными на нем символическими родовыми знаками, считавшимися священными. Чур охраняет человека от всякой «порчи», «нечистой силы».Видимо, поэтому мы иногда и говорим:«Чур меня»,когда хотим защититься от чего-то нехорошего.
В. О. Ключевский писал: «Обоготворённый предок чествовался под именем чура, в церковнославянской форме щура; эта форма доселе уцелела в сложном слове пращур… Предание, оставившее следы в языке, придаёт Чуру значение, одинаковое с римским Термом, значение сберегателя родовых полей и границ».

http://www.dazzle.ru/spec/bogi-15.shtml

Comment: Вы серьёзно?

Comment: Вы у Шанского Н.М. спрашиваете? К сожалению, он не может Вам ответить.

Comment: Нет, у  Софии. Ведь, наверняка, у вас и своё мнение имеется.

Comment: @София, зачем вы приделали к неплохому ответу мифотворчество родноверов, неоязычников, религиозные представления которых не имеют почти никакого отношения к верованиям древних славян?

Comment: Убираю неоязычников и родноверов.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы ответить на вопрос «кто такой **щур**?», вспомните выражение: «Чур, меня! Чур!»
**Щур** или **чур** – это домовой, а домовой – это дух предка, отсюда и происходят пращуры – наши предки.

Answer (score 0):

Странно, а прямого ответа так и нету.

Щур (=Чур) - это предок. Далекий, точное число колен до которого подзабылось или не имеет значения. Поскольку духи предков имели обыкновения поселяться в жилищах славян (под порогом, например), то к ним и обращались в реплике "Чур меня!". Остальное - у Софии.

Answer (score 0):

Есть статья из Полного Церк.-Слав. словаря Г. Дьяченко:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]